# Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); Not working

Tags: oracle, class, load, driver

```
public class JdbcConnectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Dynamically loading the driver so that it will register.
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");              
    }
}
```

When I am running above code I am getting following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)   at
>   JdbcConnectionTest.main(JdbcConnectionTest.java:14)

Please let me know if someone has a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the fully qualified class name :oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver